# C# Create Lambda Expression Dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, func

I work with Dapper and I try to create auto-mapped method for inner join.

This is the example of the models:

```
public class User
{
    public long IdUser { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
} 

public class Page
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long IdUserCreatedPage { get; set; }
    public User UserCreatedPage { get; set; }
}
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM "PAGE" INNER JOIN "USER" ON "PAGE"."IdUserCreatedPage" = "USER"."IdUser"
```

if I write code mannualy I will write this:

```
public List<Page> GetPage(IDbConnection dbConnection, string sql)
{
    return (List<Page>)dbConnection.Query<Page, User, Page>(sql, 
        (Page p, User u) =>
        {
            p.UserCreatedPage = u;
            return p;
        },
        splitOn: "IdUser").ToList();  
}
```

Now, what I want is create dynamically the `Func<TFirst, TSecond, TOut>` that I need for mapping the object. 

Can someone help me? Thank you very much.


P.S. I know that in this case it does not make sense create it dynamically, but this it's only a simply version of all the project of auto-mapping.

Comment: This might be of some help : https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions

Comment: This is a question-and-answer site. If you have solved it, add and accept an answer. The practice of putting [SOLVED] into titles on forum sites is because those sites aren't designed for finding answers to questions, like this one is.

Comment: @JonHanna Ok, I did it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Finally I find the way to do what I want. 

This is the code of the function that Generate `Func<TFirst, TSecond, TOut>`:

```
public static Func<TFirst, TSecond, TFirst> MappingDynamicFunc<TFirst, TSecond>()
{
    ParameterExpression paramFirst = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirst), "paramFirst");
    ParameterExpression paramSecond = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSecond), "paramSecond");

    MemberExpression memberExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramFirst, "UserCreatedPage");
    BinaryExpression assign = Expression.Assign(memberExpression, paramSecond);

    LabelTarget labelTarget = Expression.Label(typeof(TFirst));
    GotoExpression returnExpression = Expression.Return(labelTarget, paramFirst, typeof(TFirst));
    LabelExpression labelExpression = Expression.Label(labelTarget, Expression.Default(typeof(TFirst)));

    BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(
        assign,
        returnExpression,
        labelExpression
    );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirst, TSecond, TFirst>>(block, new ParameterExpression[] { paramFirst, paramSecond }).Compile();
}
```

And this is the "GetPage" method:

```
public List<Page> GetPage(IDbConnection dbConnection, string sql)
{
    return (List<Page>)dbConnection.Query<Page, User, Page>(sql, 
        MappingDynamicFunc<Page, User>(),
        splitOn: "IdUser").ToList();  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at PredicateBuilder. http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Here is some pseudo code

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SomeClass>();

if (SomeCondition)
{
     var inner = PredicateBuilder.False<SomeClass>();
         inner = inner.Or(p => p.Category == "WhatEver");
         inner = inner.Or(p => p.Category == "");

     predicate = predicate.And(inner);
}

...

var result = MyIEnumerable<SomeClass>.AsQueryable()
                                     .Where(predicate)
                                     .FirstOrDefault();
```