# How dynamic or usage in EF Core Where?

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core

My sample code block is as follows, I have a string array. This array consists of dynamically not predetermined

```cs
var query = _dbContext.Table..;
List<string> arr= ...;
// output: arr=X,Y,Z

foreach (var item in arr)
{
    query = query.Where(f => f.XNumber.Contains(item))
}
```

The output of the expression I want to do should be like this

```cs
f.XNumber.Contains(item) or 
f.XNumber.Contains(item) or 
f.XNumber.Contains(item) or
```

but every where causes an and operator. How can I convert it to OR operator? Is there a method like `WhereWithOr`?

Edit: my data looks like this:

```
XNumber:
12331X,
5113Y,
5123,
Z5123,
...
```

I'm trying to find items containing X or Y and Z in field XNumber

Comment: What is preventing you from using the `||` operator?

Comment: I am creating a query dynamically.
Something like this is not possible

foreach(){
 query=query.Where(f=>f.XNumber(item) || )
}

Comment: You might want to turn the query around if possible, and do something like `.Where(f => arr.Contains(f.XNumber))`, that should be translated to an [sql in](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQKit's `PredicateBuilder`

```cs
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New(query);
foreach (var item in arr)
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(f => f.XNumber.Contains(item));
}
query = query.Where(predicate);
```

Or my extension [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316)

```cs
query = query.FilterByItems(arr, (f, item) => f.XNumber.Contains(item), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing there is adding multiple Where clauses to the query. EF then combines them into a single Where claure that, obviously, joined by ANDs.

So youdneed to work with the inner predicate and add that to a single Where in your query.

An [answer here suggests using PredicateBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52739923/13744)

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with a single `Where`, something like this:

```
query.Where(f => item.Any(i => f.XNumber.Contains(i)))
```

This will check if it can find a match for at least 1 item in your array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
"could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated"

With iqueryable this is not possible